# How to pass a struct array into a function

Tags: c, function, data-structures

I want to pass a struct array into a function and I keep getting an error. I'm not sure how to do it in general as I was never taught. I've done some googling but I can't find anything. Can you guys help me out and explain why this is not working? Here's the code of the entire program (it's small, just a test program):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #define hour 60


int getNum(void);
int distance(int start, int end , int flight_time[5], int flight_layover[5]);

int main(void)
{
    int user_start=-1;
    int user_end=-1;
    int travel_time=0;

struct flight 
{
    int flight_time;
    int flight_layover;
};

struct flight flights[5]=
{
        {4 * hour + 15, 1 * hour + 20},
        {3 * hour + 58, 0 * hour + 46},
        {3 * hour + 55, 11 * hour + 29},
        {2 * hour + 14, 0 * hour + 53},
        {3 * hour + 27, 0 * hour + 0}
};

printf ("Hello sir. Please enter you starting city:\n");
user_start=getNum();
user_start--;

printf ("Good. Now enter the city you would like to end it:\n");
user_end=getNum();
user_end--;

travel_time = distance(user_start,user_end, flights[5].flight_layover,          flights[5].flight_time);

printf ("The total travel time from %d to %d is %d.",user_start, user_end, travel_time);

return 0; 
}



int distance(int start, int end , int flight_time[5], int flight_layover[5])
{
    int total_mins=0;
    int i=0;
    for (i=end+1;i--;i=start)
    {
        total_mins=total_mins + flight_time[i] + flight_layover[i];
    }

    return total_mins;
}


int getNum(void)
{
    char record[121] = {0}; 
    int number = 0;
    fgets(record,  121, stdin);
    if(sscanf_s(record, "%d", &number) != 1 )
    {
        number  = -1;
    }
    return  number;
}
```

Comment: I made a mistake when I put int flight_time[5] and int flight_layover[5]. I need the entire array in there, not just 5 (index 5, or 4 to be more precise).

Comment: Be aware that a parameter declaration `int flight_time[5]` is *exactly* equivalent to `int *flight_time`; the `5` is ignored.  Suggested reading: section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `distance` function is all wrong. Since you have a `struct` that contains `flight_time` and `flight_layover`, you want to pass an array of these `structs` to the function, not an array of each of those `int` values. ie.

```
int distance(int start, int end, struct flight flights[])
{
    int total_mins=0;
    int i=0;
    for (i=end+1;i--;i=start)
    {
        total_mins=total_mins + flights[i].flight_time + flights[i].flight_layover;
    }

    return total_mins;
}
```

Changed the function signature and the line inside the `for` loop.

Then where you call `distance`, you can change the call to:

```
distance(user_start,user_end, flights)
```

That'll pass a pointer to the start of your array (`flights`), and `user_start` and `user_end` will specify the bounds of the array to be used to calculate the distance.

**Also note that you could be accessing indexes out of the `flights` array's bounds.** I especially don't understand why you have `i=end+1`, perhaps you wanted `i = end - 1`?

You also have the condition and decrement part of your for loop reversed, this is how I think it should be:

```
for (i = start; i <= end; i++)
```

**EDIT:** Obviously your function prototype needs to be updated, and your `struct`s should be declared before they're used anywhere (including before the prototypes). [Here's](http://codepad.org/aq9itfqO) the whole code with the modifications I've mentioned.

Also, be careful with your `getNum` function, since it can return -1 upon error and you'll cause undefined behaviour if you're accessing elements *before* your array. You should also check the user input to ensure that the start and end values are between 1 and 5, and are decremented so that they're valid array indexes between 0 and 4.

Also, you can use the `+=` operator to add to the current value of a variable, ie

```
total_mins=total_mins + flights[i].flight_time + flights[i].flight_layover;
```

can be changed to:

```
total_mins += flights[i].flight_time + flights[i].flight_layover;
```

**EDIT2:** One other thing. By convention, constant `#define`s should be in upper-case, ie.

`#define HOUR 60` as opposed to `#define hour 60`.

Comment: yeah I thought that if I had the for loop start at end it would decremment (i--) and it would skip one. I also forogt to mention, that the struct flight (I don't have error checking yet), the way it works is I have to have the flight citys displayed and where the user can go to from each city. So, the way it works, is city 1 can only go to city 2, and city 2 can only go to city 3. I just wanted to make sure it was adding up the mins correctly of the total travel time.

Comment: Also, putting stuct flight flights[] gave me lots of errors. The way you did.

Comment: @Robsta you need to change the function prototype also and move the struct declarations, let me upload the full code.

Comment: @Robsta, there you go, it'll all compile now. Also note that I changed `sscanf_s` to `sscanf` for it to compile.

Comment: @Robsta if you already downloaded the updated code, do it again. I just realised that `end` in your `distance()` `for` loop was *inclusive*, so it should in fact be: `for (i = start; i <= end; i++)`

Comment: Hey thank alot! This worked well. There are a few things I have to change though. This is part of a code that I need for a bigger program, like I said before this is a just a test program, but there are some guidlines I need to follow (it's a school course), meaning, that I cannot have any global variables. I'm not sure about strucs if they need to be global or not to run, but I believe if there able to not be global then they cannot be.

Comment: @Robsta Yeah you'd usually avoid global variables like your `flights` array. Besides having `hour` as lower-case, when it *should* be upper-case by convention, the rest of your code looks fine convention-wise. No other warnings with gcc with `-Wall` flag for extra warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like this:

```
int distance(int start, int end , struct flight flights[5])
{
    int total_mins=0;
    int i=0;
    for (i=end+1;i--;i=start)
    {
        total_mins=total_mins + flights[i].flight_time + flights[i].flight_layover;
    }

    return total_mins;
}
```

which is then called as

```
travel_time = distance(user_start,user_end, flights);
```

Comment: Should be `flights[i].flight_time` not `flights.flight_time[i]`.

Comment: @AusCBloke: Fixed. Thanks for letting me know, I didn't noticed.